# Microsoft SQL using pyodbc, store variables from database table?

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

**Context:** I have a large project where a user inputs his name, and then at the end of the session his name is attributed a score using the `INSERT INTO` method. Note that I am using PyGame for the whole project, if that will have an impact on the solution.

**Question:** I need a way, probably using a function called at the end of a session, to take the first 5 scores (like a leader board) that come from the score table, and store them in a variable (potentially a dictionary?) and with that I could then display these scores to the user. What can you use in pyodbc to take variables and store them in a variable?

**Additional information and code:**

Here is my function for the saving of variables to the database:

```
def TableScore(self):
        conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=[Redacted]\[Redacted];'
                      'Database=Highscore;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Highscore.dbo.Highscores')

        cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Highscore.dbo.Highscores (Name, Scores)
                VALUES
                (?,?)
                 ''',(self.PlayerName, self.score)
                 )

        conn.commit()
```

And here is the function I will be using to display scores and call the function that saves the scores to the database:

```
def show_go_screen(self):
        #Welcome screen
        if not self.running:
            return
        self.image = pg.image.load('WallPaper.png')
        self.screen.blit(self.image, (0, 0))
        self.draw_text("You died!", 48, White, Width /2, Height / 4)
        self.draw_text("Score: " + str(self.score), 22, White, Width / 2, Height / 2)
        self.draw_text("Press any key to restart", 22, White, Width / 2, Height * 3/4)
        if self.score > self.highscore:
            self.highscore = self.score
            self.draw_text("New Highscore!", 22, White, Width / 2, Height / 2 + 40)
            with open(path.join(self.dir, HS_File), 'w') as f:
                f.write(str(self.score))
            self.TableScore() #Calls saving to database function

        else:
            self.draw_text("Highscore: " + str(self.highscore), 22, White, Width / 2, Height / 2 + 40)
        pg.display.flip()
        self.wait_for_key() #Waiting for user input to start new game.
```

I hope this is enough information, if you need more to answer I'll be happy to keep this updated!

Thank you!